# Connecting mysql remotely via free host

Tags: php, mysql, hosting, web-hosting

I registered on 000webhost and I can connect to mysql db pages that are uploaded there via:

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass') or die('Could not connect to database');
mysql_select_db('name') or die('Could not select database');
```

But it seems [it does not allow connecting remotely](http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=27).

Is there any free host which has mysql db and allows remote connections ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try [heliohost.org](http://heliohost.org)
I used it sometime back and they got good service as well.The only problem is the registration get filled too quickly

Comment: Thanks it worked for me with python too!  Make sure to do the settings just like they say.  http://wiki.helionet.org/Mysql#Connecting_Remotely

Comment: Also, the delay on a ping to heliohost.org is kinda slow with about 100 ms and a paid server gives you about 40 ms.

Answer (score 6):

000webhost does not provide MySQL remote access for free accounts, 
have [a look](http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=27), so either go for an upgradation

Or try http://www.freemysql.net for remote free mysql server, But again its free hence very slow,

```
mysql_connect('SQL**.FREEMYSQL.NET', 'USER', 'PASS') or die('Could not connect to database');
mysql_select_db('DBNAME') or die('Could not select database');
```

Do not use "localhost"