# Can not connect to Mysql database of 000webhost.com

Tags: java, php, mysql, database, connection

```
$mysql_host = "mysql12.000webhost.com";
$mysql_database = "a1819767_ramen";
$mysql_user = "a1819767_naruto";
$mysql_password = "naruto1234";
```

I am trying to connect to mysql database using java. But it's not working. However I can access the database from phpMyAdmin of the webhost cpanel.

```html
static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://mysql12.000webhost.com/a1819767_ramen";

    //  Database credentials
    static final String USER = "a1819767_naruto";
    static final String PASS = "naruto1234";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
```

But I get the following error...

```
Connecting to database...
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure


The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:355)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2461)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2498)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2283)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:822)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:404)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:215)
    at FoodBank.main(FoodBank.java:24)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:241)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:305)
    ... 15 more
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 27 seconds)

[image: Ping Screen Shot]

[image: Web host credentials]

Comment: is there a firewall in between?

Comment: There is a firewall : `3306/tcp filtered mysql` . Maybe there is a different port than default or you can't access it from outside

Comment: It is Very unusual that hosts allow remote access to a mysql database. It is occasionally possible but you have to setup a user account that is allowed to login from a remote address.

Comment: I think this answers my question....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831915/connecting-mysql-remotely-via-free-host

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL from 000webhost doesn't allow you to connect from external applications(remote connections). It allows only connections from the same domain where it is hosted. If you want to establish remote connections then you have to upgrade to special tier.

Please check: [000webhost remote connections](https://www.000webhost.com/website-faq/how-can-i-connect-to-mysql-from-my-computer-27)

Answer (score 0):

Remote MySQL connections are disabled for security and server performance reasons.

However remote MySQL connections will be enabled if you upgrade your account to our premium hosting service at https://www.hostinger.com/special/000webhost